# Evaluate each environment variable and set it back in ubuntu

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, environment-variables

I'm trying to write a shell script which reads all the environment variables, evaluate them for included env. variable with in them and re-export after evaluvation.

**Example** - I've an environment variable exposed like this:

```
echo $JVM_OPTS                 
-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1600m  -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=${CONTAINER_IP} -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing -XX:CMSIncrementalDutyCycleMin=0


echo $CONTAINER_IP 
10.44.214.63
```

Now, I need to eval "**JVM_OPTS**" variable and substitute the value of ${CONTAINER_IP}  in $JVM_OPTS to 10.44.214.63. Finally, set this evaluated value back in JVM_OPTS variable.

**Sample Output:**

```
echo $JVM_OPTS                 
    -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1600m  -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=10.44.214.63 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing -XX:CMSIncrementalDutyCycleMin=0
```

My Analysis so far:
I wrote the below code to do the task

```
#!/bin/bash

for path in $(printenv); do
    path=`eval echo $path`
    echo $path
done
```

printenv would give the entire env. variable along with values. I just need the name and then use the value.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Where/when is `JVM_OPTS` being assigned? Can you not just arrange for `CONTAINER_IP` to be set *before* `JVM_OPTS` is assigned so that it can expand the value normally?

Comment: No. Actually CONTAINER_IP is being sent as an argument to Docker run. 
While the variable JVM_OPTS is being set when the Docker is being compiled.
So until run time I won't know the value of CONTAINER_IP.

Comment: You could append to the pre-set `JVM_OPTS` with the `CONTAINER_IP` value at boot time even if the rest of the value is set at image creation time.

Comment: also asked at http://superuser.com/q/1062094/4714

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
for path in $(compgen -e) ; do
    eval "$path=\"${!path//\"/\\\"}\""
done
```

But see [Why should eval be avoided in Bash, and what should I use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17529220/4154375) for information about the pitfalls of using `eval`.

`compgen -e` prints a list of the environment variables.

`${!path}` evaluates to the value of the variable whose name is `$path`.

`//\"/\\\"` replaces `"` with `\"` in the variable value, to preserve embedded double quotes.